# Remove content from PHP session variable

Tags: php

I am reading data from a database where I have no control over the database and it's values.

I am using PHP sessions to display this data.

When outputting `$row['Type']` is it possible to change the output based on matches the database returns?  I tried to search on solutions and am finding nothing close to this in previous questions.  Thanks.

**Example:**

If 'Fishing Boat' is output in the $row['Type'] I want to intercept that and change it to 'Vessel'

**Code Snippet:**

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row){
    $txt .='<h3>'.$row['Type'].'</h3><br/>' ;
```

Comment: do you want a simple comparison ?  `if(Fishing Boat) then print Vessel ` ?

Comment: `(strcmp($row['Type'] , 'Fishing Boat') == 0 ? 'Vessel' : row['Type'])`

Comment: I've updated the question to make more clear.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code intercept and changes the session values:

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row){

     switch ($row['Type']) {
    case "Fishing Boat":
        $_SESSION['records'][$key]['Type'] = 'Vessel';
        break;
    case "Real Estate":
        $_SESSION['records'][$key]['Type'] = "Homes For Sale";
        break;
      // there is no need for "default:"
    }


    $txt .='<h3>'.$_SESSION['records'][$key]['Type'].'</h3><br/>' ;\
}
```

Now your `$_SESSION` has changed and you can print it once again :

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row){
    $txt .='<h3>'.$row['Type'].'</h3><br/>' ;\
}
```

Comment: if there is no match case the `$output` will be blank

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for suggestion, edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

if you mean you want to change the output if you have 'Fishing Boat' in `$row['Type']` then that what you will need

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row)
{
  if(strcmp($row['Type'] , 'Fishing Boat') == 0)
    $txt .='<h3> Vessel </h3><br/>' ;
  else
    $txt .='<h3>'. $row['Type'] .'</h3><br/>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simple have to test the value in question and then concatenate either the `$row['Type']` or the replacement value onto `$txt`.

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row){
    if ($row['Type'] == 'Fishing Boat' ) {
        $txt .= '<h3>Vessel</h3><br/>';
    }else{
        $txt .= '<h3>'.$row['Type'].'</h3><br/>';
    }
```

Or using a ternary operator you can

```
foreach($_SESSION['records'] as $key=>$row){
    $txt .= ($row['Type'] == 'Fishing Boat' ) 
                ? '<h3>'Vessel'</h3><br/>' 
                : '<h3>$row['Type']</h3><br/>';
```

Comment: `$txt .= '<h3>Vessel</h3><br/>';`